# How to effectively unbind() hoverintent() from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, unbind, hoverintent

I'm using the [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin to create hover drop-downs in my Bootstrap 3 navigation. However, for smaller sizes I want to still use the native click trigger to activate the dropdowns and not the hover. I'm trying to use [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/), which allows me to call a function when the screen size enters a specified width, and another when it leaves that width. This is my code so far:

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 767px)", {
 match : function() {
  hoverIntentInit();
 },
 unmatch : function() {
  removeHoverIntent();
 }
});

function removeHoverIntent(){
  // remove the hoverintent() function <-- this is what I need
}

function hoverIntentInit(){
  var config = {
     timeout: 900,
     over: showMenu,
     out: hideMenu};
 $('.dropdown').hoverIntent(config);
}
function showMenu(){
  // code that shows the dropdown (not important)
}
function hideMenu() {
  // code that hides the dropdown (not important)
}
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151278/jquery-unbind-or-rebind-hoverintent) from few years ago. However, the answers over there either don't work or they they remove both the hoverIntent and the click events from the elements which is not what I want (I want the native Bootstrap click event to remain).

Please help me with this, I've spent more than a day on this and still I can't find a solution.

Thanks!